# Calling a specific service class or controller method of spring boot application using Sparklauncher

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-spark, spark-launcher

In a spring boot application,I have couple of service classes . Each service class is doing some spark transformations. I am testing locally using controller which is staring the sparksession and doing some transformations and closing the session. but how can we call a specific service or a controller method in spring boot to execute using spark launcher. Any help is appreciated.. I am new to spark and java.. A sample example will be very helpful Thanks!!
 how to call a particular service (dcpayservice.applytransformations() or the controller method to run the spark job

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Someone who doesn't have spark knowledge but knows Java well may be able to help you by looking up spark api documentation if you provide some code as an example and show an attempt of solving your question.

Comment: protected SparkLauncher createLauncher(final SparkJob job) {
                SparkLauncher launcher = new SparkLauncher()
                        .setMaster(job.getMaster())
                        .setAppName(job.getName())
                        .setDeployMode(job.getDeployMode())
                        .setAppResource(job.getResource())
                        .setMainClass(job.getMainClass());
           
        }

Comment: controller class

Comment: @GetMapping("/test1")
            public void applytest1Transformations() {               
                enaService.applyTransformations();      
                   }        
            @GetMapping( "/test2")
            public void applytest2Transformations(){             
                dcPayService.applyTransformations();      
                       }